# How to have auto increment sequence in postgres increment by 4 instead of 1

Tags: postgresql

I am using a command to change the number the auto increment sequence starts at for the id field:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE orders_order_id_seq RESTART 14028;
```

I would like to make this increment by 4 instead of by 1. Is this possible?

I know this is a very short question but I don't have code examples I can provide for this. I have not found anything in the documentation or other questions that address this query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.
Try

```
alter sequence orders_order_id_seq INCREMENT 4
```

[PostgreSQL Documentation. ALTER SEQUENCE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-altersequence.html)

> increment
>   The clause INCREMENT BY increment is optional. A positive value will make an ascending sequence, a negative one a descending sequence. If unspecified, the old increment value will be maintained.